# SELECT all rows from table and All related rows from linked table

Tags: mysql, json, pdo

Is there a single query that will return all rows from a primary table AND all rows for a related table based on an ID. The related tables may have multiple rows for the same ID from the primary table.
At the moment I get all the rows from the primary table and then loop through that and use a function to get rows from related tables. this works but doesn't seem particularly efficient.

ie

```
SELECT * FROM primaryTable 
AND (SELECT * FROM tableImages) as Images 
AND (SELECT * FROM tblReviews) as Reviews
```

This needs to be output as JSON like this...

```
{id: 1
name:"name1",
address:"address1",
reviews:{reviewID:25,review:"reviewText", reviewID:38,"reviewText2"},
images:{imageID:1234, file"file1.jpg",imageID:3456, file:"file3.jpg"},
latitude:12.3456,
longitude:34.5678
},
{id: 2
name:"name2",
address:"address2",
reviews:{reviewID:29,review:"reviewText", reviewID:57,"reviewText2"},
images:{imageID:12, file"file1.jpg",imageID:34, file:"file3.jpg"},
latitude:12.3456,
longitude:34.5678
}
```

Comment: try to use joins

Comment: Go read up on JOINs.

Comment: Tried this but seems to take even longer SELECT * FROM tblMarkers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblImages ON tblMarkers.ID = tblImages.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReviews ON tblMarkers.ID = tblReviewsID

Answer (score -1):

you have to use join for this ,sample query is shown below

SELECT * FROM primaryTable  ptable INNER JOIN secondTable stable WHERE ptable.id = stable.id

just copy this to your sql editor and replace with your tables it will work

you can refer join [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: JOIN alone will return an array that is not nearly close to the example provided

Comment: can you explain the query with sample